# Link to the current page okay for SEO?

Tags: seo, links

I have a website and one SEO guy told me to remove cyclic links that link to the current page. We don't work with him anymore. So I can't ask for details.

So are this links bad for and should be removed?

[image]

Comment: The link was removed because it is not necessary to answer your question. By adding it you make this question specific to your website which makes it off topic here resulting in the question being closed.

Comment: I don't consider adding the link as spam and it helps to better understand my  problem. Yes this is question specific to my website. And I guess all other sites have similar problem. So I don't get your position. Stop removing useful info from my question!

Comment: Unless the link adds value to the question there is no reason to add it. The question should be answerable without having to leave Pro Webmasters. Furthermore... you should focus on providing better details what you mean, because I'm sure I'm not the only one but what are "cyclic links?

Comment: @SimonHayter well, for example you are on the main page. There you click   menu -> home (it is link that will lead you to the current page again.) This is what seo guy called cyclic link. As far as get it. Or for example you are on sedan page. You click menu -> sedan and page reloads. It is also a cyclic link to the current page.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. If you are on page RV... and they click RV... again... nothing happens? is that what you mean?

Comment: I can't tell you more because we don't work with this guy anymore

Comment: @SimonHayter If you are on page RV... and they click RV- page just reloads and that's all

Comment: Yep... sorry that's what I meant content remains the same. The SEO guy is talking rubbish.

Comment: I'll provide you an answer now that I understand.

Answer (score 2):

First off, there is no such SEO term as a cyclic link. You only need to Google the term and your be overwhelmed with topics that have nothing to do with SEO.

> [**Cyclic is a Greek Latin Word**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cyclic)
>
> adjective
>
> 1. revolving or recurring in cycles; characterized by recurrence in cycles.
> 2. of, relating to, or constituting a cycle or cycles.
> 3. Chemistry. of or relating to a compound that contains a closed chain or ring of atoms (contrasted with acyclic ).
> 4. Botany.
>
>    1. arranged in whorls, as the parts of a flower.
>    2. (of a flower) having the parts so arranged.
> 5. Mathematics.
>
>    1. pertaining to an algebraic system in which all the elements of a group are powers of one element.
>    2. (of a set of elements) arranged as if on a circle, so that the first element follows the last.

*Active Current Page Links*

It is absolutely normal and perfectly acceptable for current page links to be clickable, they can appear anywhere on the page, should it be within the menu, the footer or even the content area, it really doesn't matter in terms of SEO.

*Improving User Experience using Current Page Links*

Using clickable active and current page can actually improve the experience, since allows users to copy the URL without having to scroll to the address bar in their browser.

Some sites like Stack Overflow use links within the headers on the page, for example over over your question title header at the top, its a link. Some sites use link icons next to the header, it really doesn't matter if you use them or not.

You can even use hashtag internal links on the same page so users can quickly find a particular spot on the page, again... perfectly valid in both terms of SEO and UX.

*Millions of sites use current page links*

W3C

[image: HTML5.1 W3C Screenshot]

Google

[image: Google Current Page Link Image]

**However... You should not abuse anchor text**

It is however possible to abuse this system and by using multiple links on the same page that link back using different anchor text for each, this is considered poor for user experience and search engines will likely punish you for over optimsiation. So, don't use multiple anchors if you can avoid it.

For example if you have 3 links on the page pointing to page RV, one in the footer, one in header and one on the page content then ideally you should use something like this:

- Header: RV
- Content: RV's for Hire
- Footer: RV

*Do not use:*

- Header: Cheap RV Hire
- Content: Awesome RV hire in Bournemouth
- Footer: Book RV Hire

*Also do not use:*

- Menu: RV links to services.html
- Menu: Limo links to services.html
- Menu: Hummers links to services.html

These are consider bad user experience because the links offer exactly the same content and likely to confuse people attempting to go from one page to another. If you have a page with all products or services, then keep it simple... Vehicles for Hire for example. Google will not 'OVER' reward for using multiple anchor texts, and enough of them is considered over optimisation.

Ensure that your anchor text and links are relevant and useful, not ones that will confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

Simon is correct that links to the current page are common.   They don't cause any SEO problems that I am aware of.

However, they are usually bad for user experience.   Users expect clicking on a link to take them somewhere.   Most users don't expect clicking on links to refresh the page.

I tend to make menus like:

```
<b>Home</b>
<a href=page1.html>Page 1</a>
<a href=page2.html>Page 2</a>
...
```

Where the current page is bold and not linked.   I find that removing the link from the menu entirely is confusing to users.  Including it unlinked gives users context that many are looking for and expect.